# Comparing the Calibration Error of Two Classifiers with a Bootstrap Hypothesis Test

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, calibration

I am currently working on a project where I would like to compare the [expected calibration error](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/expected_calibration_error) (ECE) between a pair of probabilistic classification models.

Given a pair of $f_1$ and $f_2$, I would like to run a one-sided hypothesis test to evaluate:

$$H_0: ECE(f_1) = ECE(f_2)\\H_A: ECE(f_1) < ECE(f_2)$$

Here, $ECE(f_1)$ and $ECE(f_2)$ would be the expected calibration error of $f_1$ and $f_2$ on an independent test set.

I am wondering how I should test this with a Bootstrap Hypothesis Test?  There seem to be multiple options for how to design this, so I am wondering what the most reliable approach would be. The simplest solution that I have in mind is to just resample $B$ subsets from the test set, compute $ECE(f_1) - ECE(f_2)$ on each subset, and then test whether $ECE(f_1) - ECE(f_2) > 0$ using a t-distribution.

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer to this? For instance given a number of estimators $f_{1}, \dots, f_{n}$ along with their ECEs $ece_{1}, \ldots, ece_{n}$, then what would be a rational way to test for the statistical significance among the ECE scores for the different estimators?